# debugging dependent projects in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Sorry about the newbie question but I could not find an answer anywhere: I have a Visual Studio 2010 project (C#) with several dependencies on other projects in the same solution. When I debug the project and try to step into code in one of the dependencies, it steps over instead. Also, it seems that it is using a previous, installed version of the dependency instead of using the one in the solution.
How can I make it use the one in the solution and allow step-into?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.

1. The dependencies' compiled versions were installed in the GAC - needed to take them out first.
2. Needed to turn on Tools->Options->Debugging->General->Enable Just My Code.
3. Needed to set Copy Local to True for each dependency in the target project.
4. Like everyone here pointed out, needed to re-build all dependencies first, in Debug mode.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: The GAC is not used if you have a local copy, so #3 overrides #1.  Did you figure out why this option was disabled? It is enabled by default.

Comment: Step 4 says to do step 4 first. Shouldn't that be step 1?

Comment: @TylerBrown No, step 4 should be done after fixing all the settings

Answer (score 2):

When you add the projects as references, add them using the "projects" tab (of the "add references" dialog) instead of adding them as binary DLLs.

Comment: Are you sure that all the projects are compiled with "debug"? Check your Build Configuration Manager.

Comment: Yes, they are all compiled with Debug.

Comment: If you right-click the properties on the references, are they "copy local = true" ?

Answer (score 2):

A project's output is only copied to the referencing project's bin folder if the dependent project is build. If the project is used in more than one solution, it may have been compiled previously but it won't update projects in the open solution. If the source is unchanged relative to the binary files, then the project is not compiled and the bin folder is not updated. Use Rebuild or Clean after opening the solution to ensure the projects are in sync.

Also check in Configuration Manager that all the projects have a Build checked.